# Jquery hovering multiple elements

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a little script that does the following;

I have three circles on a row. If I hover one all three have to slide to the left on top of each-other and the one I pointed on top of the stack. In the example the blue one.

Afterwards all three circles have to slide back to there original position.

[image: RGB example]

This is what I got. Yes it is working but...

1. it is not working properly.
2. I am wondering if there is a better approach

```
$('.circle').hover(
    function(e){
        $(this).css({'z-index' : '99'});
        $('.circle').animate({'left' : '0px'},1000);
    },
    function(e){
        $(this).css({'z-index' : '0'});
        $('.circle-red').animate({'left' : '0px'},1000);
        $('.circle-blue').animate({'left' : '200px'},1000);
        $('.circle-green').animate({'left' : '400px'},1000);
    }
);
```

Comment: it might be good to give a jsfiddle sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the mouseleave function is being fired when the circle moves away from the mouse. It would make more sense to have everything move to the circle that you hovered over. That way it could snap back to normal when you leave the circle.

Anyways, my approach was to create the container around the objects that is used to trigger them snapping back to place. Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cz366/2/

One thing to keep in mind is always use `.stop()` before `.animate()`. This will prevent the animation from queuing up on you. Stop will clear/kill the animation queue on the element.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your example in jsfiddle. It works fine now. But for my personal understanding... still figuring out how and why the script works by adding the data to the container.

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation using mostly CSS transitions:

HTML

```
<div class="circles">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
// Just basic looks. Notice the position: absolute; and the z-index defaulting to 0.
.circles {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;  
}
.circle {
  position:absolute;
  display:inline-block; 
  z-index:0;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #222;  
  transition: 500ms ease-in;
}
// Positioning for each one using the CSS3 nth-of-type pseudoselector.
.circle:nth-of-type(1) { background:red; left: 0%}
.circle:nth-of-type(2) { background:blue; left: 40%}
.circle:nth-of-type(3) { background:yellow; left: 80%}

// Matched items. jQuery will set all items' data-active attribute to the current active element.
.circle:nth-of-type(1)[data-active="0"],
.circle:nth-of-type(2)[data-active="1"],
.circle:nth-of-type(3)[data-active="2"] { z-index: 2;}

// We'll send all the circles to the same position depending on which is active
.circle[data-active="0"] { left: 0%; }
.circle[data-active="1"] { left: 40%; }
.circle[data-active="2"] { left: 80%; }
```

JS

```
$('.circle').on('mouseenter',function() {
  var index = $('.circle').index( $(this) );
  $('.circle').attr('data-active', index);
});

$('.circle').on('mouseleave',function() {
  $('.circle').attr('data-active', '');
});
```

**[CODEPEN HERE](http://codepen.io/ajf-/pen/bjHph)**

**What is going on here?**

jQuery sets `[data-active]` to the current index (circle 1 is 0, circle 2 is 1, circle 3 is 2 - Note the difference in the numbers) using the index() method.

We use the :nth-of-type CSS3 pseudoselector to match against the `data-active` attribute. If circle 1 has `[data-active=0]`, then we'll give it a z-index of 2 so it can be on top.

All items with `data-active=0` will move to the same position of circle 1: 10% left. All items with data-active=1 will move to left:40% and so on.

*Note:* for extra fun, add  transform: rotateY(180deg); after the z-index:2; property.

The movement is made with the transition: 500ms ease-in; property, and automatically sequences the animation when the `left` property changes.

This could be more concise but the way the code is structure, I think it's easier to understand.

Comment: Great answer, but it would be very good to explain what exactly you are doing here ;)

Comment: so far, I see the circle flipping and it turned white.  Want to make the color stay and care to make it just like what the OP has: 3 circles overlapping each other but with a slight offset so that you see layer 1, 2, and 3?